# Поведение FloatingActionButton при раскрытии клавиатуры

Tags: android, coordinator-layout

Имеется два активити, унаследованные от `AppCompatActivity`, в разметках обоих классов есть `CoordinatorLayout` и вложенный `FloatingActionButton`, при этом поведение `FAB` при появлении клавиатуры кординально различается. В `MainActivity` `FAB` всплывает вместе с клавиатурой, а во второй активности при появлении клавиатуры нет. Ниже привожу разметки, классы практически идентичны.

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="ru.appchief.application.cargocalculator.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_48dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

И практически идентичная вторая разметка

activity_checkpoint.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/checkpoint_coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/content_check_point" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add_checkpoint"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_location_white_48dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

В данный момент меня интересует, почему во втором активити `CoordinatorLayout` не координирует поведение дочернего объекта, как в первом активити?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CoordinatorLayout` никогда не реагирует на клавиатуру. Тут дело лежит глубже.

Чтобы Activity подстраивалась под изменение положения клавиатуры, необходимо указать в манифесте для Ваших активити аттрибут: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410499/difference-between-adjustresize-and-adjustpan-in-android

Comment: Спасибо, отчасти вопрос решен. Но поведение в любом случае отличается. В первом случае FAB появляется над клавиатурой без указанной строчки в манифесте, но при появлении и исчезновении SnackBar все равно проваливается за клавиатуру, во втором с указанной вами строчкой изменяется размер экрана (уменьшается на размер клавиатуры) и соответственно FAB после исчезновения SnackBar никуда не проваливается. Можно конечно и там и там прописать в манифесте строчку, но я хочу понять в чем причина отличного поведения.

Answer (score 0):

Вся проблема кроется в строке

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

в файле `activity_checkpoint.xml`. Обуславливается это тем, что `FAB` "по-дефолту" имеет *своё поведение* (`FloatingActionButton.Behavior`). А так как эта строка присваивает значение переменной типа `Behavior` внутри экземпляра `FAB`, то и стандартное поведение становится недоступным. Если `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` нужен вам лишь для закрепления `FAB` на уровне `AppBarLayout` то используйте

```
app:layout_anchor="@+id/id_вьюхи_к_которой_хотите_прикрепиться"

//гравитация относительно вьюхи, к которой прикрепились
app:layout_anchorGravity="стандартные переменные типа Gravity"
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, забыл убрать строчку, без нее проблема осталась, но комментом выше проблему отчасти удается решить.